# How to generate a board object with cell and column properties filled out correctly?

Tags: javascript, minesweeper

I'm trying to create a function which generates a board.

```
function createBoard(rowSize, colSize, mineNum) {

  let board = { cells: []}

  let boardSize = rowSize * colSize;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < boardSize; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < rowSize; j++){
    board.cells[i] = {
      row: i%rowSize,
      col: i%j,
      isMine: false,
      isMarked: false,
      hidden: true
    }
  }
  }
return board
}
```

The current properties for rows and columns are just wild guessed. How would I create a board where all the column and row properties are filled out correctly? As in, no two cells would have the same row and column properties.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not too far off! You don't need to multiple columns and rows because your nested loop is actually taking care of that for you. You can just use `i` and `j` directly and push to the `cells` array.

```js
function createBoard(rowSize, colSize, mineNum) {
  const board = { cells: [] };
  for (let i = 0; i < colSize; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < rowSize; j++){
      board.cells.push({
        row: j,
        col: i,
        isMine: false,
        isMarked: false,
        hidden: true
      });
    }
  }
  return board;
}

const board = createBoard(10, 10);

console.log(board);
```

Comment: thanks so much! I was just overcomplicating it. Have a good day!